# Magento 2 - CLI Installation - MySQL Access Denied despite correct authentication

Tags: magento2, database, installation, magento2.3

I've been following the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html) for Magento 2.3 and am now stuck while trying to set it up on the command line.  I'm executing the following:

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=[password] --backend-frontname=admin --admin-firstname=name --admin-lastname=name --admin-email=admin@test.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=[password] --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

Obviously, in place of [password] I have my actual passwords.

I get the following response:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magento'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

This response would indicate that my user or password or database name are incorrectly entered.  **But they aren't.**  I have checked my command many times, and am fully able to login with `mysql -u magento -p` with the same password.

[image: MySQL next to Magento error]

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue:  I didn't escape the special characters in my password.

I was able to run the command successfully by adding a backslash before the special characters (! # ' " ` & ; and $).